# Sacar IDs sin que se repitan de una tabla con SQL

Tags: sql

veréis, tengo una tabla en SQL llamada **mensajes** , esta tabla contiene 2 IDs, una del receptor y otra del emisor, la fecha y el mensaje en sí.

Intento extraer con qué personas ha hablado, por ejemplo, el miembro con id 1 pero cuando hago la query me sale esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna forma de que solo salgan las IDs sin que se repitan y en una sola columna?

Gracias.

Comment: Imagino que lo que quieres que salga: Id Emisor 1 se ha mensajeado con los IDs: 2,3,4 (en forma de lista?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto podría resolver tu problema, de una forma bastante simple:

**Consulta:**

```
SELECT id as idsConQuienHablo FROM (
  SELECT m1.miembo_id_emisor as id FROM mensaje as m1 WHERE miembo_id_emisor != 1
     UNION
  SELECT  m2.miembo_id_receptor as id FROM mensaje as m2 WHERE miembo_id_receptor != 1
)
```

> UNION : sin (ALL) elimina duplicados entre columnas con el mismo
>   nombre.

Comment: Muchas gracias! He utilizado la idea del UNION y he conseguido sacar la información de una tirada, dejo aquí el code:

select distinct miembro_id_emisor from mensaje where miembro_id_emisor != 1
union
select distinct miembro_id_receptor from mensaje where miembro_id_receptor != 1;